# Scraping text data from different domain urls using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is there any way to scrape only the text data from different domain urls in Python?

For example in [this](https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/news/airbnb-is-getting-ripped-apart-for-asking-renters-to-donate-money-to-landlords/articleshow/76968577.cms) website the text is in a different block than in [this](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-07-15/sas-soldiers-allegedly-plant-gun-on-dead-bodies-in-afghanistan/12452964) page. I would like to write a single function that would allow me to scrape the text from both these websites at the same time. Is that possible in Python?

Comment: Be more precise on what you want to do. Request both websites separately and concat the result text is one approach to do but you have to know what you want to extract from these pages.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible thing in `python` is to **scrape** the whole text of a page. You can do that using that code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/news/airbnb-is-getting-ripped-apart-for-asking-renters-to-donate-money-to-landlords/articleshow/76968577.cms')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
texet = soup.find('html').text
print(texet)
```